# Does PageSpeed Insights recognize native lazy loading on iframes

Tags: javascript, youtube, pagespeed

I'm currently trying to get a better PageSpeed Insights score for our homepage. One of the biggest issues according to PageSpeed Insights is an embedded YouTube video (more precisely YouTubes [base.js](https://www.youtube.com/s/player/10df06bb/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js) file which gets loaded when embedding a YouTube video). As the video is further down the page i added native lazy loading to the iframe. Now it looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_CODE?rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

It works perfectly when using a real browser. The YouTube video does not load at the beginning but if i scroll further down as it should be. But according to PageSpeed the YouTube video which shouldn't even be loaded is still reportet as the biggest blocking resource.

So my question is: did i do something wrong, or doesn't PageSpeed recognize native lazy loading for iframes and i need another JS based solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, so it's not just you! Did you find a solution/workaround?

Comment: @AndyP Sadly not. There is propably a custom JS solution, but I didn't put further work into it, as it works in a real browser. Just not for PageSpeed Inisghts.